# ListBox does not include newly added lines to source table because of RowSource

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a UserForm `UserForm1` with a ListBox `ListBox1`. The ListBox is filled with Data from the ListObject `lstDaten`. The Listbox can then be filtered by consultant `cbBerater`, product `cbArtikel`, country `cbLand` as well as a free text search via the textbox `tbSuche`.

On Initialisation the listbox is filled by using `ListBox1.RowSource = lstDaten` but when filtering via the `Private Sub butAddItem_Click()` I start with

```
ListBox1.RowSource = vbNullString 
ListBox1.Clear
```

to clear that out. I also tried `ListBox1.RowSource = ""`

Via another Userform a new line with data can be added to `lstDaten`

Here comes my problem: If I use any of the filtermethods, the new line is being shown in the listbox. But if none of the filters are applied, the new entry does not show up.

I think the problem might be with the `.RowSource` because if I delete that in the `UserForm_Initialize` it seems to work. But I don't understand why the listbox would not understand that there is a new line if i take out `.RowSource`

If after taking out `.RowSource`, put it back in, nothing changes. It still does not show the new line.

The RowSource has over 500 lines of Data. Filling it all with `.RowSource` when no filters apply is very fast. Adding every line indiviually works, but is a lot slower and really feels like it should be possible.

I hope you can help me find my error. Here is the `butAddItem_Click()`. If you need any other sub, please tell me.

```
Private Sub butAddItem_Click() 'Suche ausführen
Dim wsDaten As Worksheet: Set wsDaten = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daten")
Dim lstDaten As ListObject: Set lstDaten = wsDaten.ListObjects("Daten")
Dim NumZeilen As Integer: NumZeilen = lstDaten.ListRows.Count
Dim colSuche As Integer
Dim strDropdown As String
Dim arrHeader As String

ListBox1.RowSource = vbNullString 'Löschen der RowSource, damit neu gefüllt werden kann
ListBox1.Clear 'Falls noch Daten in Liste sind, werden diese entfernt

'Wenn durch alle gefiltert werden soll, festlegen des Starts und des Endes
If cbHeader.Value = "Alle" Then
    loopStart = 1
    loopEnde = lstDaten.ListColumns.Count
Else 'Wenn nach einer bestimten Spalte gefiltert werden soll, wird diese hier definiert
    loopStart = lstDaten.ListColumns(cbHeader.Value).Index
    loopEnde = loopStart
End If

For j = 1 To NumZeilen 'Loop durch die Zeilen zum Vergleich mit dem Suchtext

    'Wenn ein Artikel ausgewählt ist, überspringe Zeilen ohne diesen Artikel
    If Not cbArtikel = "Alle" And Not lstDaten.DataBodyRange(j, lstDaten.ListColumns("Artikel").Index) = cbArtikel Then
        GoTo NextIteration
    End If

    'Wenn ein Artikel ausgewählt ist, überspringe Zeilen ohne diesen Artikel
    If Not cbBerater = "Alle" And Not lstDaten.DataBodyRange(j, lstDaten.ListColumns("Berater").Index) = cbBerater Then
        GoTo NextIteration
    End If

    'Wenn ein Land ausgewählt ist, überspringe Zeilen ohne diesen Artikel
    If Not cbLand = "Alle" And Not lstDaten.DataBodyRange(j, lstDaten.ListColumns("Land").Index) = cbLand Then
        GoTo NextIteration
    End If

For k = loopStart To loopEnde 'Loop durch die Spalten
    If InStr(1, lstDaten.DataBodyRange(j, k), tbSuche.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or tbSuche.Value = "" Then 'Vergleich Zelleninhalt mit Suchtext

        arrDaten = lstDaten.ListRows(j).Range 'Bei Übereinstimmung wird Zelleninhalt dem Array hinzugefügt.
        ListBox1.AddItem

        For i = 0 To 9 'Hinzufügen des Arrays zur Liste
            ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, i) = arrDaten(1, i + 1)
        Next i
        GoTo NextIteration
    End If


Next k
NextIteration:
Next j

End Sub
```

PS: I know, parts of the code like GoTo are not optimal here, but it works :D

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Try qualifying the `ListBox` with the name of the `Userform` like: `Userform1.ListBox1.RowSource=""`

Comment: Just a response to your PS part - you could replace your `GoTo NextIteration` with `Exit For`.

Comment: @Blackcat: Unfortunately it made no difference

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook: Wouldn't that end the whole loop?

Comment: If you set a string value in the UI of the Userform for RowSource, the string there cannot be deleted with VBA. So if you call again the Userform the data will be the original range. What you can do that from the VBA every time you detect the actual range of data and set it to the `Userform1.ListBox1.RowSource = "new_range"`

Comment: Sorry, yes - was only looking at the GoTo in the `k` loop.  That will jump out of the k loop and take you to the next iteration line.  Yes in the `j` loop it would end the procedure.